# Fresnel coefficient

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

I dont think I have enough backgrounds for optics.

I am sorry for asking this elementary question.

I am reading a paper Phyc Rev A, Vol 59 # 6, 1999

they introduces discontinuity matrix $$\Delta_{ij}$$ which describes the boundary condition for the transfer of the electric field from left to right across a discontinuous $$n_i --> n_j$$ interface, accounting for the Fresnel reflection and transmission coefficients.

The incidence angle is 0

they introduces this matrix as

$$\Delta_{ij}=\begin{bmatrix}
        \delta_{ij}^+ & \delta_{ij}^- \\
        \delta_{ij}^- & \delta_{ij}^+ \\
                \end{bmatrix}$$

where
$$\delta_{ij}^+=\frac12(1+\frac{n_j}{n_i})$$ and $$\delta_{ij}^-=\frac12(1-\frac{n_j}{n_i})$$

note that $$n_i$$ and $$n_j$$ are complex numbers.

I know the Fresnel equation with respect to the incidence angle.

I think the Fresnel coefficient should be $$(\frac{n_i-n_j}{n_i+n_j})^2$$ for R... but it is different

how can I get that coefficient

I actually want to know how the $$\Delta_{ij}$$ changes with respect to the incidence angle.

Comment: Are you looking at isotopic and homogeneous materials? In this cast $\Delta_{ij}$ is not a function of angle. Can you link to the actual paper, this would help.

Comment: http://journals.aps.org/pra/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevA.59.4736

Comment: Pay wall. Maybe you can summarise by adding a bit more context.

Comment: Thanks boyfarrell, metrix delra is not a function of theta because the paper considers only 0 incidence angle, please see the 4739 page

Comment: You need to add more context to this question. For example I didn't even understand why it would be a function of angle because the refractive index doesn't change with angle (see my above point about isotropic and homogeneous materials).

Comment: the author defines the delta metrix which having fresnel coefficients. I learned Fresnel eqn so i tried find that coeff. but the value is different.

Comment: but the fresnel coefficient is function of incidence angle, right? so I thought delta metrix also should be function of theta because it is Fresnel coeff.

Comment: I applogize that the question is not clear enough for you

Comment: Sorry, I can't help until I can read the paper of the question is updated.

Comment: is it illegal to send you a pdf version of that paper ?

Comment: @eric Please **edit** the question to include the relevant clarifications from the comments.